# Calabash iOS cal app showing up blank when Running Cucumber

Tags: ios, ios7, cucumber, bdd, calabash

I followed the steps to set up Calabash-iOS as specified in their README: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios (the fast way). When I run the -cal target by clicking the standard Play button in XCode, everything is working great.

However, when I run the cucumber command from my Terminal, it opens up a blank app with just a white screen and none of the view components. Any ideas on how I would debug this?

[image]

Using XCode 5.1.1, Calabash iOS 0.9.168, Simulator 7.1 (4-inch and 4-inch 64-bit)

Comment: Are you launching from within a tmux session?  There is a known issue with calabash/xctest when launched from inside a tmux session:  https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/issues/308 Also, triple check that you built (in Xcode) for the simulator you are trying to launch from the Terminal.

Comment: Whoa, I use iTerm, so will try the normal Terminal later today. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure what caused this. I got my co-worker to install Calabash on his machine, and it worked. I deleted my code, cloned it again, re-installed it, and it still had the same problem. I re-downloaded again and put it into a different directory path (another folder), and it works!

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue, where I would make changes to the app and when running 'cucumber' it would not pick up my new changes. I believe what help me resolve the issue was to reset the simulator and its contents, exit out of any simulators already running, and make sure I am not running the interactive calabash-ios console. Hopefully this helps, and if I find a better solution I will let you all know!

Answer (score 0):

You should delete application from Simulator (check what simulator was used in calabash build) and re-install it again. You can use Xcode for this or just re-run it from terminal. It should work then.

No needs to reinstall calabash or other packages.